# Keras accuracy not increasing over 50% on binary CNN problem

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, cntk

I am using keras to process the following subset of my data:

```
5000 images of class A
5000 images of class B
```

With 1000 of these images for each class being used as validation. Scaling the images to 96x96x3 channels and normalised to be within the range 0-1. I am using the following model:

```
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu", input_shape=inputshape))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

And then training the model in the following way:

```
sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=sgd, metrics=["accuracy"])
```

However the accuracy rarely (just by chance) increases over 50% accuracy:

```
Epoch 1/100
8000/8000 [==============================] - 23s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6939 - acc: 0.5011 - val_loss: 0.6932 - val_acc: 0.5060
Epoch 2/100
8000/8000 [==============================] - 22s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6938 - acc: 0.4941 - val_loss: 0.6941 - val_acc: 0.4940
Epoch 3/100
8000/8000 [==============================] - 22s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6937     - acc: 0.4981 - val_loss: 0.6932 - val_acc: 0.4915
Epoch 4/100
8000/8000 [==============================] - 22s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6933 - acc: 0.5056 - val_loss: 0.6931 - val_acc: 0.5060
Epoch 5/100
8000/8000 [==============================] - 22s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6935 - acc: 0.4970 - val_loss: 0.6932 - val_acc: 0.4940
```

I don't think the problem is the data itself, as I have used an alternative machine learning method and got over 94% accuracy with the exact same images (except using just 5 training images for each class, but that's beside the point).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Oh! In case it matters: I'm using the CNTK backend.

Edit: Here is the code I use to read in the images, which also normalises the pixel values to the 0-1 range:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array

healthy_files = sorted(os.listdir("../../uninfected/"))
healthy_imgs = [cv2.imread("../../uninfected/" + x) for x in healthy_files]
data = []
labels = []
for img in healthy_imgs[:5000]:
    resized = cv2.resize(img, (96, 96)).astype(numpy.float32) / 255.0 # normalise data to 0..1 range
    arr = img_to_array(resized) 
    data += [arr]
    labels += [0]
# The for loop above is then repeated over the other half of the dataset, with the labels line using the label [1] instead
data = np.array(data, numpy.float32)
```

Edit 2: Here is the output of model.summary():

```
Model built:
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 94, 94, 32)        896
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 92, 92, 32)        9248
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 46, 46, 32)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 44, 44, 64)        18496
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 42, 42, 64)        36928
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 21, 21, 64)        0
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 28224)             0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 256)               7225600
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 257
=================================================================
Total params: 7,291,425
Trainable params: 7,291,425
Non-trainable params: 0
```

I noticed that there were no activation layers explicitly listed in this summary so I changed the model to this:

```
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=inputshape))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
#model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
#model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
#model.add(Dropout(0.5))
#model.add(Dense(10, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))
```

Which gave a summary output of this:

```
Model built:
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 94, 94, 32)        896
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 94, 94, 32)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 92, 92, 32)        9248
_________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 92, 92, 32)        0
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 46, 46, 32)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 44, 44, 64)        18496
_________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)    (None, 44, 44, 64)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 42, 42, 64)        36928
_________________________________________________________________
activation_4 (Activation)    (None, 42, 42, 64)        0
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 21, 21, 64)        0
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 28224)             0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 64)                1806400
_________________________________________________________________
activation_5 (Activation)    (None, 64)                0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 65
_________________________________________________________________
activation_6 (Activation)    (None, 1)                 0
=================================================================
Total params: 1,872,033
Trainable params: 1,872,033
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Needless to say, the results remain the same...

Comment: Are you sure that your labels are correct (eg 1 for class B, 0 for class A)? Are you shuffling them during training? Are you using a reasonable batch size?

Comment: Have you normalized the images? Have you tried an optimizer with adaptive learning rate like `Adam` or `RMSprop`? What if you lower the learning rate of `SGD` to `1e-3`?

Comment: @jmsinusa The labels are definitely correct before I split the training data using scikit-learn. I don't shuffle them between epochs but they are randomly shuffled each time the script is run. I've tried various batch sizes with no difference in result.

Comment: @today I haven't tried normalizing the images.. any suggestions how to do that? I've tried Adam and RMSprop with no success. Also tried lowering the learning rate and that didn't help either..

Comment: @today I just realised by normalise you probably meant bringing the values between 0 and 1. I have done that, yes - sorry for the confusion

Comment: @thedarkspoon The loss is barely changing as well. Maybe the weights are not updated during backprop. Did you try different initialization schemas? For ReLU activation [He initialization](https://keras.io/initializers/#he_normal) might be a better choice. The fact that you used only 5 images per class before matters a lot since it's way easier to overfit a smaller training set. I suggest you reduce your training set to 5 samples per class as well and see whether you can overfit. That helps narrowing down the problem.

Comment: @thedarkspoon Would you please include the normalization codes as well?

Comment: Could you also try adding another Dense layer with 10 nodes before the output layer? I think that might help the network converge.
I would also like to see the normalisation code. Is this a public dataset?

Comment: @a_guest I noticed that too. I'll look into the He initialization. I probably didn't make that very clear - when I used 5 samples per class, I was using a method other than neural networks - and the 5 samples per class gave a 94% accuracy over the rest of the dataset (27560 images in total). This leads me to think that A) it wasn't overfitting (because it worked for the whole dataset) and B) 5 images provides enough information to distinguish between the classes with a good degree of accuracy, or at the very least, better than random selection.

Comment: @today I've added the code to the main post, thanks

Comment: @jmsinusa I tried adding the dense layer. No luck, exactly the same behaviour was observed. Please check the updated code in the main post. Unfortunately this dataset is not public and I don't have permission to share it at the moment.

Comment: @thedarkspoon I see. Anyway I would try these two things: 1) Select a very small subset of you training data (< 5 samples per class, or even down to a single image) and see whether you can (over-)fit this small set (i.e. don't run validation data in parallel, just try to get the train loss to zero / accuracy to 100%). If this doesn't work then something with the network architecture is broken. 2) Take any other (public) data set (narrow down to two classes if necessary) and try whether you can (over-)fit this one with your current architecture. If you can, this hints a problem with your data.

Comment: @thedarkspoon And also (or rather especially) try with Dropout switched off, also for the above suggested test cases, as it acts as some kind of regularization. Also have you tried running without Dropout in general? And did you try BatchNorm instead of Dropout?

Comment: @a_guest Ah, now I see what you're saying. I just tried with one sample per class and also with 5 samples per class - no luck, accuracy never reached 1.0 and fluctuated around 0.5. So I guess the network is broken. I'll try with another dataset shortly. Regarding your other comment, I have tried with and without Dropout - same result unfortunately (both with the full dataset and the very small subset).

Comment: @thedarkspoon Could you include the result of `model.summary()` as well? Maybe there is some inconsistency regarding the `data_format`.

Comment: @today Absolutely; please see the main post.

Comment: @thedarkspoon Okay, and I suppose you convinced yourself that these two images (and their labels) actually make sense (e.g. by looking at them). Could you also try and fit each of these images separately (i.e. having only a single image in your training set)? If it still doesn't work it can be really narrowed down to the network setup.

Comment: @thedarkspoon Strange indeed! Nothing further comes to my mind... just as a (last) shot from me: try `RMSprop` with a much lower learning rate, say `1e-4` or even `1e-5` (don't change its other parameters) and let it train for more than 20 epochs.

Comment: @thedarkspoon Another thing is, you could be unlucky with weight initialization and hence end up with a lot of dead ReLUs; here I suggest taking a look at the activations manually for each layer (check `model.layers` or `model.get_weights()`) and make sure these are non-zero for most of the nodes. Also you could try using ELU or LReLU activation instead of ReLU. Besides, you seem to use uncentered data, so transforming to zero mean during data preparation and adding BatchNorm layers could help the optimizer in finding optimal weights.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for all your comments. I've solved the issue - please see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, after trying all the suggestions the wonderful people had in the comments, I had no luck. I decided to go back to the drawing board, or in this case, try it on an alternative computer. My original code worked!

In the end I narrowed it down to the backend - I was using CNTK on the first computer, and Tensorflow on the second. I tried CNTK on the second computer, and it worked perfectly... So I decided to reinstall CNTK on the first computer. This time, the code worked perfectly. So I have no idea what was broken initially, but it had *something* to do with my install of CNTK. I guess in the end, this whole Q&A doesn't really help anyone.. but if anyone experiences a similar issue - try the suggestions in the comments on the question - some really good advice there. And if that doesn't work... try changing your backend!

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

also it is usually a bad idea to use dropout in convolutional layer, use batch normalization instead.

Comment: Can you share any reference that support this view? It's contrary to my understanding.

Comment: This is not true. Its perfectly fine to use dropout in conv layer.

Comment: please check this two links to get more details, there are some papers also in the reddit link: https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/42nnpe/why_do_i_never_see_dropout_applied_in/;  https://towardsdatascience.com/dont-use-dropout-in-convolutional-networks-81486c823c16

Comment: Just because there's some people saying that dropout shouldn't be applied to conv layers doesn't mean its the rule. In semantic segmentation of images, dropouts are still applied. https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.09326 To my knowledge, there hasn't been any paper that has came out and say dropout hurts generalisation.

Comment: it doesn't hurt generalization, it. hurts the accuracy. it. cause under-fitting. but as usually this is not a general rule, just empiric one. since we have few parameters in convolutional layer. that's why dropout is considered to be less performant compared to dense layers.